# How to access a value inside an array of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've downloaded 10 followers for each of the two accounts in the array and putted them inside a dictionary and then inside an array. Now i need to access 4 of the followers screen name of the first acc and 4 of the followers screen name of the second but when i try so it gives me an error. Below is the code i used and the result of the download of the followers

```
twitter_accounts = ["AccName1", "AccName2"]
res = {}
pbar = tqdm_notebook(total=len(twitter_accounts))

for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
    inner_structure = []
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=twitter_account,
                              skip_status=True, include_user_entities=False).items(10):
        val = page._json
        inner_dict = {}
        inner_dict["name"] = val["name"] 
        inner_dict["screen_name"] = val["screen_name"]
        if inner_dict not in inner_structure:
            inner_structure.append(inner_dict)

    res[twitter_account] = inner_structure
    pbar.update(1)

pbar.close()
print("done.")
for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:

    #print(len(res[twitter_account]))
    display(res[twitter_account]['screen_name'])
```

Below im going to upload the photo of the result of `display(res[twitter_account])`[image]

Also im uploading the error i get when i try to access `display(res[twitter_account]['screen_name'])`[image]

I want to access the screen name of the followers i got so i can download from 4 of them their followers. So the followers of Followers of the first 2 accounts

Comment: Please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images. Your question is unclear, can you be more specific? Are you asking how to index lists and dictionaries? There's a blatant typo in your code, is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you have >= 4 followers:

```
for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
    for in in range(4):
        display(res[twitter_account][i]['screen_name'])
```

Comment: By doing so the result i get are the followers of Acc1 and Acc2? Or the followers of the followers of Acc1 and Acc2?

Comment: @MKK Since I don't fully understand the structure of the data I cannot tell you that. You will get first 4 of the 10 downloaded followers for each of two accounts, based on your description

Comment: But what if i wanted to save the 8 results in an array instead of displaying them? i tried to add another for loop with j in range(8) and writing array[j]=res[twitter_account][i]['screen_name'] but it gives me an index out of range error in this line @AlexanderPushkarev

Comment: @MKK You WILL get index out of range if there's less than 8 elements in the list. I would suggest posting a new question for this - something like "how do I get n elements from list or less, if there's not enough elements in the list"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to access the array

```
for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
    inner_structure = res[twitter_account]  # access the array
    for inner_dict in inner_structure[:4]:  # go through the first 4 elements
        display(inner_dict['screen_name'])
```